# Understanding flowable backpressure rxjava2

Tags: rx-java2

I put together this dummy example to try to understand `backpressure` a little better:

```
Flowable.range(1, 100).onBackpressureDrop()
                      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                      .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSubscriber<Int>() {
                        override fun onStart() {
                          request(1)
                        }

                        override fun onComplete() {
                          Log.d(this@MainActivity::class.java.simpleName, "onComplete")
                        }

                        override fun onNext(t: Int?) {
                          Log.d(this@MainActivity::class.java.simpleName, t.toString())
                          Thread.sleep(1000)
                          request(1)
                        }

                        override fun onError(t: Throwable?) { //handle error}
                      })
```

I have an extremely slow `Subscriber` that consumes data from a very fast `Flowable`. And I'm instructing the Flowable to `onBackPressureDrop()`. Despite of this, my output looks like this (from 1 to 100)

```
07-16 23:07:21.097 22389-22389 D: 1
07-16 23:07:22.100 22389-22389 D: 2
07-16 23:07:23.102 22389-22389 D: 3
07-16 23:07:24.104 22389-22389 D: ...
07-16 23:07:24.104 22389-22389 D: ...
07-16 23:07:24.105 22389-22389 D: 99
07-16 23:07:25.105 22389-22389 D: 100
07-16 23:07:25.107 22389-22389 D: onComplete
```

I was expecting missing elements since the subscriber is extremely slow, but that isn't the case, all number from 1 to 100 are printed to the console, one every second.

Next, I tried to request all values at once. So I replaced `request(1)` in `onStart` with `request(Long.MAX_VALUE)` and remove `request(1)` from the `onNext` call. but it still prints the number 1 to 100 with no missing elements.

**So I wonder how can I simulate a subscriber missing events for a slow subscriber? 
How can I make a backpressure exception happen?**

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`observeOn` has a default internal buffer size of 128, that's why you don't see elements dropped as it can simply buffer up all the 100 elements you are generating. You can set the buffer size to 1 via `observeOn(mainThread(), false, 1)` and experience drops.

Comment: That did it! thanks. I experience drops but only if the `.onBackPressureDrop()` operator is present. Why don't I get an exception when I remove it? it prints all values normally even though the buffer is full.

Comment: Because `Flowable.range` supports backpressure and can interoperate with `observeOn` no matter how big the buffer is, never signalling a MBE. Btw each operator on `Flowable` has a **Backpressure** javadoc entry that explains how it behaves.